# Pandas drop rows appearing above/below string match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe from a .txt file, and I am only interested in the data that appears between the `<Header>` tags.

```
          0          1  
0 webmaster      @.com
1  <Header>     121112
2  ReportID       5353
3      Date   20210630
4      Type      DMV13
5 </Header>       None
6       ZIP      90279
7     State         WV
```

I therefore want to drop all other rows, but can't do it on position because the `<Header>` tags appear in different rows depending on the file. So is there a way to drop every row above/below a string match, so that the output looks like:

```
          0          1  
0  ReportID       5353
1      Date   20210630
2      Type      DMV13
```

Comment: If the criteria are all same, this? df[df['0'].isin(['ReportID', 'Date', 'Type'])]

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the `index` of the rows where the sign `<` or `>` is contained using `str.contains(r'..|..')`, and then filter your dataframe with `iloc`:

```
# Extract the min and max index of rows that contain '<' or '>'
min_i = df[df['0'].str.contains(r'<|>')].index.min()
max_i = df[df['0'].str.contains(r'<|>')].index.max()
```

---

```
# Filter by index location
df.iloc[min_i+1:max_i,:].reset_index(drop=True)

          0         1  t
0  ReportID      5353  0
1      Date  20210630  0
2      Type     DMV13  0
```

Note that [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) uses is an integer position indexing based lower boundary being an inclusive boundary and upper boundary being an exclusive boundary. Hence the +1 on `min_i` no addition on `max_i`

Answer (score 0):

This as well:

```
start = df[df['0']=='<Header>'].index[0] + 1
end = df[df['0']=='</Header>'].index[0]
df.iloc[start:end].reset_index(drop=True)

          0         1
0  ReportID      5353
1      Date  20210630
2      Type     DMV13
```

Or the comment I left produces the same result

```
df[df['0'].isin(['ReportID', 'Date', 'Type'])]
```